# Ensime inferior scala mode

Tags: scala, emacs, slime, ensime

I've setup Emacs + Ensime for scala.

I'm able to start sbt console inside emacs using C-c C-v s

If i start scala console inside emacs using C-c C-v z, I get the following error

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_33).
scala> 
Failed to initialize compiler: class scala.reflect.BeanInfo not found
```

What is the fix for this error? How do i get scala console running inside Emacs?

Comment: How did you set up Emacs+Ensime? Did you follow some specific set of instructions, or did you just do something random and have it not work? If the later, try the former.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into a similar error recently, but here's how I worked around it (but I don't know how to fix it, so this is only half the answer). What I did was to customize the `ensime-inf-default-cmd-line` variable to have the value: `'("sbt" "console")`. Which will indeed start the interactive Scala environment.

EDIT:

Here's relevant parts from `.emacs`, but I'm not sure it will matter / will be the same in every install:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 ;;
 ;; more stuff ...
 ;; I'm not sure this line is correct / makes any difference
 '(ensime-inf-cmd-template (quote ("sbt" "console" "-classpath" :classpath)))
 ;; This variable is used to launch the interpreter
 '(ensime-inf-default-cmd-line (quote ("sbt" "console"))))

(require 'scala-mode2)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.scala$" . scala-mode))
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/ensime/elisp/")
(require 'ensime)
(add-hook 'scala-mode-hook 'ensime-scala-mode-hook)
```

I've installed `scala-mode2` from MELPA. Installed `sbt` version 0.12.0 by downloading an RPM from their site. I had previously JRE and JDK installed, the active version is OpenJDK 1.7. Scala installed is 2.9.2. I don't know how to identify Ensime's version :|

Comment: Can you pls share .emacs config for this?

Comment: I had this issue with scala 2.9.2. Switching to scala 2.10.1 fixed this issue somehow!